# How can I linearise this nonlinear proportional relation constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, nonlinear-programming, linearization, convex-optimization

My optimisation problem has a constraint in the form

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*{35}{l}}
\text{}\hspace{16.5mm}\text{ C4:} \hspace{2mm}\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,1}L_{u}:\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,2}L_{u}:\cdots:\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,C}L_{u}=\psi_1:\psi_2:\cdots:\psi_C
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This nonlinear and makes the problem even more complex.

Here $L_{u}$ and $\psi_{c}$ are known parameters.

I will be satisfied with approximate proportional relation, e..g,
C4 can be

$\text{ C4:} \hspace{2mm}\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,1}L_{u}:\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,2}L_{u}:\cdots:\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,C}L_{u}\approx\psi_1:\psi_2:\cdots:\psi_C$

How can I deal with this nonlinear constraint?

Comment: I'm not sure Iunderstand what C4 is.  Is it that the first sum divided by the second sum equals $\psi_1$,  the seconds sum divided by the third sum equals $\psi_2$, etc.? if so, just multiply out the denominator, i.e., first sum equals $\psi_1$ times second sum, etc. If that is not what C4 is, you need to make it clear.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I think it means that the ratio of the $i$th sum to the $j$th sum is $\psi_i/\psi_j$, but your idea to clear the denominator still applies.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, RobPratt is correct. Lets say for example, $\psi_1=\psi_2=\cdots=\psi_C$, then all the summations on the left should be equal to each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the comments (thanks @RobPratt), C4 looks like
$$\frac{\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,1}L_{u}}{\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,2}L_{u}} = \frac{\psi_1}{\psi_2}$$
with similar constraints for other ratios.

Just multiply both sides by the denominator, which males it a linear constraint.
$$\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,1}L_{u} = \frac{\psi_1}{\psi_2}\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,2}L_{u}$$
Similarly with the other constraints in C4.

This is then a MILP.

If you only require the proportions to be approximately satisfied, one way of doing that is to add a term $a_i$ (declared as an optimization variable) on the right-hand side of the ith of these constraints, and add the inequality constraints $-f \le a_i \le f$ where $f$ is the allowed fudge (tolerance) factor for constraint satisfaction. This is still a MILP.

You could instead make the tolerance a multiplicative factor of the ratios of the $\psi 's$. This introduces binary, continuous product terms, which can be linearized using standard techniques well-covered in this forum.

Or change the equality constraints to double-sided inequality constraints building in the allowable tolerance, rather than introducing new variables. This can be done with either the additive or multiplicative tolerance.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please see my edit. I have slightly modified my objective.

Comment: That's a very different problem. I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: since $d_{u,c}$ is a binary variable, looks that equality constraint will provide infeasible solution most of the times. So, we may need to minimise the value of $f$ (the allowed tolerance). How can we achieve that?

Comment: since $d_{u,c}$ is a binary variable, looks that equality constraint will provide infeasible solution most of the times. So, we may need to minimise the value of $f$ (the allowed tolerance). How can we achieve that? I mean how can I minimise $f$ with $\frac{\psi_1}{\psi_2}\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,2}L_{u}-f\le \sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,1}L_{u} \le \frac{\psi_1}{\psi_2}\sum_{u=1}^U d_{u,2}L_{u}+f$

Comment: You can add a penalty term to the objective function. You will have to decide the scale factor, and perhaps which norm of f to use 9for instance (1, 2, inf0, which all consider in different ways the errors across the individual constraints. Or, as I suggested, pick an allowable tolerance, then optimize using that tolerance with no penalty term on objective.